# hasattr(np.array(1), '__iter__') is True but TypeError thrown when looping over np.array(1)

Tags: numpy

On Numpy version 1.21.1,

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(1)

hasattr(arr, '__iter__') # Returns True

for i in arr: # Throws TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
    print(i)
```

What's the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Did you try calling `arr.__iter__` directly? The _existence_ of the method doesn't mean it won't throw an error when called.

Comment: I did not. `arr.__iter__()` throws the same `TypeError`. `arr.__iter__` gives me `<method-wrapper '__iter__' of numpy.ndarray object at 0x7fdc5f728810>`

Comment: Then you've answered your own question. The method _exists_, but when you call it there's an error.

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to how an iterator method can exist for an object yet one can't iterate over said object.

Comment: Because when you call the method, to try to get an iterator to iterate over, **it throws an error**.

Comment: OK. I get it now. Thank you.

Comment: 0d array has lots of affinities to `array scalars`, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because the array doesn't have any dimension to iterate over (it's just one value)

To iterate over it, create your array like `np.array([1])`

```py
>>> np.array(1).shape
()
>>> iter(np.array(1))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
>>> np.array([1]).shape
(1,)
>>> iter(np.array([1]))
<iterator object at 0xabcd000>
```

While instances of `numpy.array` have a `__iter__` method, they internally make a direct check for whether they're 0-dimensional and raises a TypeError when attempting to iterate if they are!

From the source code:
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/ffcf508951f646c2ae02c2a0583b884f7a9163e8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/arrayobject.c#L1700-L1702

```c
static PyObject *
array_iter(PyArrayObject *arr)
{
    if (PyArray_NDIM(arr) == 0) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,
                        "iteration over a 0-d array");
        return NULL;
    }
    return PySeqIter_New((PyObject *)arr);
}
```

Comment: Sure, but why does `hasattr(arr, __iter__)` return `True`?

Comment: @VictoryOmole It might be that all arrays have an `__iter__` even 0-d arrays, but the error is only raised after calling `__iter__`, when numpy is checking for its size.

Comment: @VictoryOmole because that method does exist.

Comment: @VictoryOmole the numpy array _has the method_, however, it directly checks for a 0-dimensional case and raises a `TypeError` when attempting to iterate (added source link)

Comment: @ti7 Ah that makes a a lot of sense. Thanks.